# Steema TCharts Axis Labels not visible

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am using a query for the data to be displayed in the chart:

```
procedure TfrmUsage.ShowIndUsage(Sender: TObject);
var
  tmpQuery: TQuery;
  mTotal: integer;
  startMon: string;
  g1: TSeriesGroup;
begin
  Series7.Active:= False;
  Series0.Clear;
  Series1.Clear;
  Series2.Clear;
  Series0.Active:= True; // member 0
  Series1.Active:= True; // member 1
  Series2.Active:= True; // membership total
  tmpQuery:= TQuery.Create(nil);
  chrtUsage.Title.Text.Clear;
  with tmpQuery do begin
    DatabaseName:= Sessions.CurrentSession.Databases[0].DatabaseName;
    SessionName:= Sessions.CurrentSession.SessionName;
    SQL.Text:= 'select trim(fname)||" "||trim(lname) from asamembr ' + ' where cust_code = :custCode ' + ' and mbr_code = :mbrCode ';
    Params[0].AsString:= Self.fCustCode;
    Params[1].AsString:= '0'; // self.fmbrCode;
    Open;
    chrtUsage.Title.Text.add('Usage for Member ' + Fields[0].AsString + ' (yellow)');
    Close;
    Params[1].AsString:= '1'; // self.fmbrCode;
    Open;
    if not EOF then chrtUsage.Title.Text.add('Usage for Member ' + Fields[0].AsString + ' (red)')
    else Series1.Active:= False;

    chrtUsage.Title.Text.add('Usage for Membership (green)');
    Close;

    SQL.Text:= 'select extend(usage_date, year to month), mbr_code, count(*) from as   ambrhis ' +
      ' where asambrhis.cust_code = :custCode ' + ' and usage_date > today - 1 units year ' + ' group by 1,2 order by 1 ';
    Params[0].AsString:= Self.fCustCode;
    try
      Open;
      mTotal:= 0;
      startMon:= FormatDateTime('mmm/yyyy', Fields[0].AsDateTime);
      while not EOF do begin
        // chrtUsage.SeriesGroups.Items[0].Show;
        chrtUsage.Axes.Bottom.Labels:= True;
        chrtUsage.Axes.Bottom.LabelsSize:= 10;
        chrtUsage.BottomAxis.Visible:= True;
        chrtUsage.BottomAxis.Axis.Show;
        if startMon <> FormatDateTime('mmm/yyyy', Fields[0].AsDateTime) then begin
          Series2.add(mTotal, startMon);
          // Series2.Add
          if Series1.Active then // make sure we have all series bars
            if Series0.Count < Series1.Count then Series0.add(0, startMon)
            else if Series1.Count < Series0.Count then Series1.add(0, startMon);
          startMon:= FormatDateTime('mmm/yyyy', Fields[0].AsDateTime);
          mTotal:= 0;
        end;
        mTotal:= Fields[2].AsInteger + mTotal;
        if Fields[1].AsString = '0' then Series0.add(Fields[2].AsInteger, startMon)
        else if Fields[1].AsString = '1' then Series1.add(Fields[2].AsInteger, startMon);
        Next;
      end;
      Series2.add(mTotal, startMon);
      Close;
    finally
      tmpQuery.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here in this code the Variable startMon need to be displayed as Label for bottom axis. Please guide how that can be accomplished. 
I have set the marks as Label and Value and then in the Bottom Axis I set the title as Marks or I also tried with Value, niether one works

Comment: You should really have a look at your indentation style. If you press ctrl+d, the ide will do it **for** you.  Oh and `with` has been depreciated due to the fact that leads to scope confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are some unknown variable types and initializations in your code to test it. But I can explain how it works in general.

By default TChart uses the labels of the first visible series found with labels. If no Series has labels, still by default, it shows the values. Ie:

```
uses Series, DateUtils;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
    startMon: string;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
  begin
    for i:=1 to 5 do
    begin
      startMon:=FormatDateTime('mmm/yyyy', IncMonth(Today, i));
      Add(i, startMon);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And the default behaviour can be modified with the `LabelStyle` property. Ie, to force the values to be shown in the example above where you have a series with labels:

```
Chart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelStyle:=talValue;
```